# Query draft knowledge articles with custom fields (lightning knowledge)

Tags: lightning-knowledge

I am doing a knowledge migration from an external KB into Salesforce. I was planning on doing the migration in multiple steps: first get the articles added and then do more updates to the articles using the ID. Problem is I can't query draft articles and their custom fields. If an article is published, I can query `Knowledge__kav` and get results. Problem is this object doesn't return any results. I can query `KnowledgeArticle` and see my draft articles, but it doesn't have any of my custom fields.

Looking at the schema, it only looks like `Knowledge__kav` has my custom fields.

Is there a way to query draft articles and their custom fields in Lightning Knowledge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. Looks like you need to include `PublishStatus` in the where clause See Salesforce [Knowledge with SOQL and SOSL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/knowledge_development_soql_sosl_intro.htm)

So adding that, I can get Draft articles.

`SELECT Id FROM Kknowledge__kav WHERE PublishStatus = 'Draft'`